# Swap columns of 2D array randomly using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to randomly Swap or shuffle columns of 2D array, provided the first and last columns are not altered.

For example, My Array:

```
 pat[0][0] = "1";  pat[0][1] = "a";  pat[0][2] = "p";  pat[0][3] = "x";  pat[0][4] = "4";
 pat[1][0] = "2";  pat[1][1] = "b";  pat[1][2] = "q";  pat[1][3] = "y";  pat[1][4] = "5";
 pat[2][0] = "3";  pat[2][1] = "c";  pat[2][2] = "r";  pat[2][3] = "z";  pat[2][4] = "6";   

// (column-1)        (column-2)        (column-3)        (column-4)        (column-5)
```

Expected Output

```
pat[0][0] = "1";  pat[0][1] = "x";  pat[0][2] = "a";  pat[0][3] = "p";   pat[0][4] = "4";
pat[1][0] = "2";  pat[1][1] = "y";  pat[1][2] = "b";  pat[1][3] = "q";   pat[1][4] = "5";
pat[2][0] = "3";  pat[2][1] = "z";  pat[2][2] = "c";  pat[2][3] = "r";   pat[2][4] = "6";   

// (column-1)        (column-4)        (column-2)        (column-3)        (column-5)
// NotAltered                                                              NotAltered
```

Please Help advise or suggest somecode in the below function so to acheive this requirement in javascript

```
function shuffle2dColumns(arr) {

 //somecode here to shuffle col's randomly except 1st and last col.

 return arr;
};
shuffle2dColumns(pat);
```

Alternatively, if Randomly shufling columns cant be done, suggest somecode to swap atleast 2 colums in specified order (like column-2 with column-4 or column-3 with column-2 something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standard shuffle function to shuffle the relevant *indexes*. Then loop through the rows to apply the same order to the actual values:

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

function shuffle2dColumns(arr) {
    let length = arr[0].length-2;
    let indexes = shuffle([...Array.from({length}).keys()]);
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        let row = arr[j]
        arr[j] = [row[0], 
                  ...indexes.map(i => row[1+i]),
                  row[length+1]];
    }
    return arr;
};

let pat = [["1", "a", "p", "x", "4"], 
           ["2", "b", "q", "y", "5"],
           ["3", "c", "r", "z", "6"]];

shuffle2dColumns(pat);

for (let row of pat) console.log(row+"");
```

So `length` must correspond to the number of columns you want to shuffle. In this case it is 2 less than the total number of columns.

In the `arr[j] =` expression, the columns that should stay in place are just referenced by their index: so in this case `row[0]` and `row[length+1]` represent the outermost two columns. The rest, in the middle, is populated with the `...` syntax, and is based on the shuffle that was applied to the indexes. The `1+i` has a `1+` because the range of shuffled columns starts at index 1.

Here is a more generic function, where you can specify the range of the columns that should be subject to shuffling. The other columns will not move.

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

function shuffle2dColumns(arr, first, last) {
    let length = last + 1 - first;
    let indexes = shuffle([...Array.from({length}).keys()]);
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        let row = arr[j]
        arr[j] = [...row.slice(0, first), 
                  ...indexes.map(i => row[first+i]),
                  ...row.slice(last+1)];
    }
    return arr;
};

let pat = [["1", "a", "p", "x", "4"], 
           ["2", "b", "q", "y", "5"],
           ["3", "c", "r", "z", "6"]];

shuffle2dColumns(pat, 0, 3); // Now also include column 0 in the shuffle

for (let row of pat) console.log(row+"");
```

Comment: can you add little more detail on the explanatoin part. like which part is responsible for not altering the 1st column values. what if i want to shuffle all columns except last column. I know im asking for more but i'd be very much greatful if you could throw some light on that

Comment: See addition to answer.